# Android - OnClickListener don't call after device rotate

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

After device rotate `button_confirm` stop call `OnClickListener`.

You can repeat it just rotate device and try click "Confirm" button. Nothing happen. But must add record to right tab and reinitialize fragment with default value.

Pice of code (`EditPurchaseFragment`)

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_purchase_fragment, container, false);

        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_confirm);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> onConfirmClick()); //Set listener

        amountTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.amount);

        changeDateButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button_change_date);
        changeDateButton.setOnClickListener(v -> showCalendar());

        chipGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_group_closeable);

        newCategoryTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.new_category);

        addCategoryButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_category);
        addCategoryButton.setOnClickListener(clickView -> {
            String text = newCategoryTextView.getText().toString();
            if (text.compareTo("") == 0) return;
            newCategoryTextView.setText("");
            addNewCategory(text);
        });

        bindRecord(record);

        return view;
    }
```

Layout (`edit_purchase_fragment`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="Amount:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="Categories:"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/new_category"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/add_category"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Add"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:id="@+id/chip_group_closeable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="Date:" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_change_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_confirm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="Confirm" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Also it happen if use fragment as dialog (`PurchaseAdapter`)

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditPurchaseFragment dialog = new EditPurchaseFragment();
            dialog.setOnConfirm(record -> {
                onChange.callback(record);
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
            dialog.lateBind(purchase.record);
            dialog.showNow(manager, "editDialog");
        }
```

Another buttons haven't this problem

[Repository](https://github.com/ProMix0/FinanceApp)

P.S. Fixed - I did set breakpoint to commented line and couldn't debug code

Answer (score 0):

The [fragments lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle) changes when the screen rotates.

To avoid this error, you can extend your fragment:

```java
public class FragmentName extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
... }
```

and implement the onclicklistener like this:

```java
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_purchase_fragment, container, false);

        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button_confirm);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        amountTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.amount);

        changeDateButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button_change_date);
        changeDateButton.setOnClickListener(v -> showCalendar());

        chipGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.chip_group_closeable);

        newCategoryTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.new_category);

        addCategoryButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_category);
        addCategoryButton.setOnClickListener(clickView -> {
            String text = newCategoryTextView.getText().toString();
            if (text.compareTo("") == 0) return;
            newCategoryTextView.setText("");
            addNewCategory(text);
        });

        bindRecord(record);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //Your button logic comes here
    }
```

Comment: I'll try it, but why it can help? Why another buttons (addCategoryButton) work correct?